# How to query database using LINQ to bring data from database based on array of months in ASP.Net MVC 5?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table like blow image:

[image]

How do I write a LINQ query to bring records of Jan, Feb, March from the table?

my query:

```
 var query = (from c in db.TheMonthlyDelivery  select c).AsQueryable();
```

I am new to LINQ please help me.

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: I don't know how to do it that is why I posted here

Comment: You didn't mentioned your attempted code initially, apart from that your query don't show any "efforts", your query is simply selecting the whole data, is that how you query your tables in database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
int[] months = { 1, 2, 3 };
var query=  db.TheMonthlyDelivery.Where(x => months.Contains(x.Date.Month));
```